# Angular 1.5 Radio Button Model

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, radio-button

I have a radio button on a page whose ng-value is being set to an "answer" object.  The model for that variable is being set to a particular element of an affiliations array.  The structure of data looks something like this:

```
var user = { affiliations: [ {question: ..., answers: ... }, ... ] }
```

In this way, each "affiliation" has a question and one or more answers.  I'm trying to create a UI for this in AngularJS like so:

```
<form name='affiliationsForm'>
<div ng-repeat="(i, affiliation) in DS_OrgAffiliations">
    <h6>{{affiliation.question.name}}</h6>
    <div ng-if="affiliation.question.questionType=='MultipleAnswer'">
        ...
    </div>

    <div ng-if="affiliation.question.questionType=='SingleAnswer'">
        <label ng-repeat="answer in affiliation.answers">
            <div>
                <input type="radio" ng-model="$parent.DS_User.affiliations[i].answers" name="{{affiliation.question.name}}" ng-value="answer"> {{answer.answer}} </input>
            </div>
        </label>
    </div>

</div>
<button data-ng-click="submitAffiliations()">save</button>
```

On my model, this actually works quite well.  I have a little glue code that handles the differences between multiple choice questions and single questions, and if I make a change to this form, the model reflects the change without issue.

The problem is that **when the form is initialized on the page, the correct radio button is never checked.**  The model will show an answer object inside the 'answers' property, but the form doesn't reflect that value.  What's more, **selecting a radio button assigns the correct answer to our model, and if I select what should be the active radio button, the model appears to not change.**

I think what is happening is that the model is being initialized with a deep copy of the correct 'answer' object, rather than a shallow copy, and the fact that this reference is different is causing an issue, despite the objects having the same content.

Is this correct?  To test this theory, I did this:

```
 <input type="radio" ng-model="$parent.DS_User.affiliations[i].answers" name="{{affiliation.question.name}}" ng-value="answer" ng-checked="$parent.DS_User.affiliations[i].answer.answer==answer.answer"> {{answer.answer}} </input>
```

Notice that the ng-checked attribute is checking a member of the answers to ensure similarity.  Unfortunately, this also fails to default the correct radio button on page load.

Any insight on this?  I've spent about an hour and a half playing with this, and my references explanation seemed likely, but I haven't been able find a thread to pull on since the ng-checked attribute failed me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I spent a little more time with this and put together a simple fiddle.  As it turns out, Angular only considers references when storing objects in ng-value, so my suggestion was actually right on.  When storing primitives, it's possible to initialize the model with a different value, but when storing objects, you need to store a reference to the actual model entry!